# How to read using sparklyr csv files located in blob storage without downloading it?

Tags: r, dataframe, azure-blob-storage, sparklyr

I´m using the following credentials auth for logging in blob storage in R:

```
library(AzureStor)

account_endpoint <- "https://mycorporation.blob.core.windows.net"
account_key      <- "mykey"
container_name   <- "mycorporation"

bl_endp_key <- storage_endpoint(account_endpoint, key = account_key)
cont        <- storage_container(bl_endp_key, container_name)
w_con       <- textConnection("foo", "w")
```

I need to read a lot of huge csv files located in mycorporation/my_folder without making download and sequentially reading using sparklyr.

What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a small number of files then, the Blob storage path **WASBS** is a simple and direct way to read files from blob storage. To access a large number of files and more complex data sets use  **mount point**.

Depending upon your requirement either choose  Blob storage path or mount point.

Note: R is not capable of doing the actual mounting .So the workaround is to mount using another language like python and read the file using the library "sparklyr" as shown below.

**Mount using python:**

```
%python
dbutils.fs.mount(
    source = "wasbs://<container>@<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/",
    mount_point = "/mnt/<mount_path>",
    extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<Storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net":"Access_key"})
```

**R notebook with `sparklyr` library** :

```
library(sparklyr)
df2 <- read.df("/mnt/dem123",source ="csv",header = "true",inferSchema = "true")
display(df2)
```

[image]

**Or**

**Configure the Blob storage** .

```
%python
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net","Access_key")
```

**Reading csv file using R**

```
library(sparklyr)
path = "wasbs://pool@vamblob.blob.core.windows.net/read-employees-csv.csv"
df1 <- read.df(path,source ="csv",header = "true",inferSchema = "true")
display(df1)
```

[image]